# Magento Calculating Incorrect Fixed Discount

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, discount

Magento does not seem to be correctly calculating the order discount.  I have a rule setup to give $10 an order between $50 and $75.

[image: Rule Conditions]
[image: Rule Actions]

But this is what happens when there are multiple items in the cart:

[image: Cart Example]

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the discount is being applied to each item individually.

In your case there are 4 items in the cart, with prices: $59.95, $3.00, $3.00, $3.00. The $10 discount is being applied to each item, and it can not exceed the item price. That's why you're getting $19 discounted in total.

In your case you may want to try the **Fixed amount discount for whole cart** apply option.